# img not shown after uploaded on server

Tags: html, css, image, upload, server

I'm working on an university project right now. I've finished everything but somehow 2 images are not shown and I can't figure out why... I've changed the names, the location of the image but it still doesnt show. the weird thing is that if I open only the image in web, it shows...

address is here :

www.hegazy.de/comic/

and the two images that don't show :

http://hegazy.de/comic/compscreen2.png
http://hegazy.de/comic/imac.png

code :

```
<div id="panel4">
<div id="compscreen"><img src="./img/compscreen.png"></div>
<div id="compscreen2"><img src="./img/compscreen2.png"></div>
```

Comment: can you share your server code?

Comment: Your working image is called `imac.png` but on your site you're referencing `iMac.png` - notice the capitalisation.

Comment: changed it but still not working... also for the two other images everything is typed in correctly.
@Caius what do you mean with server code?

Comment: The 'm' of "imac" is still capital...

Comment: yeah it seems to take some time to be fully uploaded :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filenames are case-sensitive. You notated `iMac.png` but your image is called `imac.png`. Your `compscreen2.png` image works, its just only white colored on a white background. So once you fixed your `imac.ong`, it should be visible.